# Set CSS Variable 'deeply' for Theming in Blazor

Tags: css, blazor, theming

**mylayout.razor.css**

```
:root {
  --clr-one: blue;
  --clr-two: red;
}
.wrapper.normal {
  --bg: var(--clr-one);
  --clr: var(--clr-two);
}
.wrapper.reversed {
  --bg: var(--clr-two);
  --clr: var(--clr-one);
}
.title {
  background-color: var(--bg);
  color: var(--clr);
}
```

**mylayout.razor**

```
<div class="wrapper @Theme">
    <div class="title">
        My Title
    </div>
    @Body
</div>
@code {
  string Theme = mycondition ? "normal" : "reversed";
}
```

Using the above, the colors of my "title" will switch depending on the value of "mycondition".  I feel like I'm on the way the being able to theme from the layout.

I can now change the :root colors and that will affect the 'themes' so I can play with those base colors until I'm happy.

Given that "title" is a child of "wrapper", I had assumed that the variables --bg and --clr assigned on the "wrapper" would propagate to all child elements.  But ...

**myroutable.razor.css**

```
.header {
   background-color: var(--bg);
}
```

**myroutable.razor**

```
@page "/myroutable"
@layout mylayout
<div class="header">
    My Header
</div>
```

The problem is that the "header" is not getting the value of the --bg variable from the layout.

Hopefully the above explains what I'm after.  Any ideas how I might achieve this?

### UPDATE

It turns out the problem was a stoopid typo in the child razor component!  I'll leave the question here though as the pattern above is one viable way of delivering theming in a razor app.

Comment: You have a spelling mistake in `backgound-color` for `.header` declaration, needs to be `background-color` (note missing `r` letter)

Comment: The above was just a minimal repro to illustrate the problem.  But, in my real project I did have a different typo.  Your question prompted me to look at the browser element view in more detail.  My problem was a bloody typo when using the variable name in my real project in the lower level component.  Thanks Mr T ...  "I pity the fool"!!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help :) please add answer instead of editing the question to help future readers ;)

Answer (score 2):

The pattern outlined in the question is fine.

The problem was a typo in using the variable name in a sub-component, so using the pattern in the question will work for dealing with theming within a particular layout.